# Convert DateTime to custom Date format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `DateTime` object with value as `2011-08-11T01:03:29+00:00` which is returned from a database.

How can I convert this to `mm/dd/yyyy` format where as the end result type should be `DateTime` object only, not string?

Comment: Can you provide some code ? Are you using ADO.NET ? Entity Framework ?

Comment: A datetime represent a date and time no matter how you display it. You need to look at something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` object is only the numerical representation of the date as 'ticks' from a constant start time (for example, January 1, 0000).  It is not the string representation.  To get a string representation, you do `ToString()` on the object.

To convert your DateTime to a string for your custom format, use

```
myDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for complete details about `DateTime.ToString()` custom formats.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx:

> "Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a user interface element or when written to a file."

Comment: Read the full question . he don't want to  result type string. he want to be datetime only

Comment: I understand the request, but his original DateTime object is all he needs.  He does not need to convert it at all.  When he needs it in his custom format, he should use his custom `ToString()`.

Comment: If he use Entity Framework . Now the table column datatype is datetime, how can he use string ?

Comment: IF the OP is using EF (the OP has not stated how he's getting this `DateTime` object) they he's going to get a `DateTime` object from Entity Framework.  When he needs to format it as 'mm/dd/yyyy' (usually for display purposes), then he'll use `ToString()`.

Comment: Why datetime format only display purposes? When we save values to table, formated date time then save . Is it wrong ??

Comment: To the computer, a `DateTime` object is simply a number.  See my quote and link above.  Only when the `DateTime` needs to be understood by a non-DateTime object does it need to be formatted (such as being shown to the user).  The object itself has no formatting inside it.

Comment: What you say ?? I used string for format then, i converted datetime to the string for he  want to be return type a datetime . thats all buddy

Comment: What Matt's trying to explain is that when you see a date, regardless of where (including MS SQL Server Management Studio) you're seeing somebody's ToString() of the underlying data.  There is no "visual representation" of a date.  It's a double-precision value...a number.

Comment: im using EF to get data and the return type which i need is datetime object only

Comment: @shiv455 so you have your `DateTime` object.  There is no need to convert it into another `DateTime` object for formatting purposes.  When you need to format it as 'mm/dd/yyyy', then just do `ToString()` on it to get your string.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a string and parse it

```
  format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDate.ToString(format), format, provider);
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

[MSDN has all answers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: ?? He just says he doesnt want the result in string.
Its a simple parse the string, where the string is a Date parsed to a string.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has functions called `ToLongDateString(`) and `ToShortDateString()` (I believe those are correct function names) and the to short one does what you want.

Comment: The `ToShortDateString()` method will return the short date format based on your current locale.  So it may return "mm/dd/yyyy", or "dd/mm/yyyy", or "yyyy/mm/dd" based on your computer settings.